# Different header/footer - remove breaks keep first page

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, footers

If this is some basic question I am sorry, but I coudn't find solution.

I am trying to create bussines letter with first page header and footer different. Since I don't know if letter is going to have more then one page, I would like to be able to delete all other pages (breaks) and to keep first page as it is. 
Right now when I delete page break, second page header/footer design becomes first page.

Is it possible to do this or is there another way of creating different header/footer on first page without page breaks?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Create the Normal Header and Footer for all pages then You can use Different First Page and create The First page Header and Footer no need to delete page breaks

Comment: And I was wondering why something simple as that can not be done I guess I was fixated on page break solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each section can have up to three different headers and three footers - for even pages, odd pages, and special ones for the first page. To enable different header and footer for the first section page, you can use the `Header & Footer Tools -> Design -> Options-> Different First Page` checkbox (this is in the contextual ribbon tab opened when you double-click on a header or footer).

Answer (score 0):

I've just been grappling with this and have found an inelegant solution:
Go to the second page (which will be in a different section), adjust the headers and footers AND WITH EXACTLY THE SAME CHARACTERISTICS (e.g. if the first section has "first page different", set the second section the same).  Then link the second section's header/footer to the previous - it'll say it's going to replace the header/footer.  Fine.  Now unlink them, then get rid of the section and the header which was on the first page (first section) will still be there.

As a point of note, I had different margins too, which also suffered from the same problem - replicating them in the second section prior to deleting the section break got the job done.  There's got to be a better way of doing this, but I can't find it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).